# Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/github_api_headers20180618-21004-yrr75i error.

Tags: mysql, tmp

I am attempting to install mysql using homebrew but I keep getting

```
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/github_api_headers20180618-21004-yrr75i
```

This is my brew config

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.6.9
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: c814199a791867ab75f90a22715e2475706b13d8
Last commit: 7 hours ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: c58fde35d617490bad4de8faeaa9e9f1c81341ea
Core tap last commit: 6 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_NO_ANALYTICS_THIS_RUN: 1
CPU: quad-core 64-bit broadwell
Homebrew Ruby: 2.3.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
Clang: 9.1 build 902
Git: 2.15.2 => /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 1.8.0_144, 1.8.0_111
macOS: 10.13.5-x86_64
CLT: 9.4.1.0.1.1528165917
Xcode: 9.4.1
XQuartz: N/A
```

OS information

```
MacOS High Sierra
version 10.13.5
```

I tried to chown my tmp file but I realize that the permission are fine.

```
drwxr-xr-x   11 _mysql  _mysql   352 Jun 18 15:42 tmp
```

How do I correct this issue?

Comment: same thing happened to me, affraid this was a homebrew's fault after i typed *brew update*